# PyQt restarts shell

Tags: python, pyqt4, python-idle

If I'm trying to create a window or prompt a file dialog in the IDLE shell, nothing opens and the shell restarts.  Is this a bug of some kind?  I can't find anything about it.  I'm new to PyQt (and Python in general) but had been able to get tutorials to work correctly.  The last day or so, if I open IDLE and import PyQt4, QtGui, etc and then run something simple like QFileDialog.getOpenFileName, the shell just restarts.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a `QApplication` before you can use anything else from PyQt. Try rereading some of the tutorials you followed, or do a few more. [This one](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/firstprograms/) for example.

In the first code sample of the above tutorial, pay special attention to these lines (I've included the comments from the tutorial for convenience):

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
```

> Every PyQt4 application must create an application object. The
>   application object is located in the QtGui module. The sys.argv
>   parameter is a list of arguments from the command line. Python scripts
>   can be run from the shell. It is a way, how we can control the startup
>   of our scripts.

and

```
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

> Finally, we enter the mainloop of the application. The event handling
>   starts from this point. The mainloop receives events from the window
>   system and dispatches them to the application widgets. The mainloop
>   ends, if we call the exit() method or the main widget is destroyed.
>   The sys.exit() method ensures a clean exit. The environment will be
>   informed, how the application ended.
>
> The exec_() method has an underscore. It is because the exec is a
>   Python keyword. And thus, exec_() was used instead.

It appears you might have forgotten about these. Or maybe you haven't realized that this means that you normally can't use PyQt with a running event loop in the interactive shell. However, there is a trick for that, see [here](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/python_shell.html).